# Flash when loading icon from ListBox in xaml windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

First, I have listbox display text and icon with template like this:

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="TreeItemTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,1,0" Visibility="{Binding NormalTextVisible}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Foreground="{Binding Colour}" Padding="{Binding ActualIndent, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>

            <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource IconButton}"  Height="42" Width="42">
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Here is my IconButton style:

```
    <Style x:Key="IconButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>                                   
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundBrush" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" CornerRadius="24" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding Content}" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The first time I go to this view, everything is ok. But when I go to another view,and then then press back key to get back to this view, the icon flashes for 1 to 2 seconds (but text and another controls are ok). 
I tried it with many ways but doesn't work (double animation for opacity, change background like phone theme)
Is there any other way out?